# Understanding Redis inside Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

I have a Spring Boot application, where I need to get data from a table when the app initializes.

I have a repository with the following code:

```java
@Repository
public interface Bookepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {

   Proveedor findByName(String name);
   @Cacheable("books")
   List<Proveedor> findAll();
}
```

Then from my service:

```java
@Service 
public class ServiceBooks {

    public void findAll(){
        booksRepo.findAll();
    }
    public void findByName(String name){
        booksRepo.findByName(name);
    }
}
```

And then I have a class that implements CommandLineRunner:

```java
@Component
public class AppRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    public AppRunner(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        bookRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

So here,when the application initializes, it queries to the Books table and caches the result. Inside the application each time I call find.all(), the cache is working, and I get the data from my cache.
So here are my 2 questions:

1. About Redis, I am not using Redis and I am doing database cache without any problem. So, where does Redis fit into this approach? I don't understand why everybody uses Redis when cache is working without needing other libraries.
2. When I call findByName(name), is there any chance to execute that query over the data I already have cached? I know I can have a cache on that method, but the cache will save data each time I search a particular name. If a name is searched for the first time, it will go to the database for that value. I don't want that, I would like that Spring performs the query using the data from the first cache where I have all Books.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to your question

1. Redis avoids the DB call as it stores your response in Memory. You can use @cacheable even in controller or service. If you use @cacheable in controller, your request will not even execute the controller method, if it is already cached.
2. for FindByName, Redis provides a nice way to store the data based on keys. 
   Refer the link [Cache Keys](https://programmerfriend.com/ultimate-guide-to-redis-cache-with-spring-boot-2-and-spring-data-redis/).
   Once you request by Name, it will get the data from DB, the next time you request with same name, it will get from cache based on the key.
   Coming back to your question, **NO** you should not do a search on your cached data, as caches are highly volatile, you cannot trust the data from cache. also searching through the cached data might affect the performance and you might need to write lines of unneeded additional code.

Comment: Hi! About your first answer.I can do the same without redis.In this example Spring uses same prebuilt CacheManager.Example :
ConcurrentMapCacheManager,EhCacheCacheManager,NoOpCacheManager
SimpleCacheManager.So my question is,Why do i need Redis ?What does it gives over those prebuilt options?

Comment: I know about Cache Keys.But ,for this example,i want to access a table it wont change in years.So i can trust on this data,so after findAll(),if i do fiindByName,can that query run trougth the memory data? Or i should call findAll,and then interate the result to find what i want?

Comment: Because it s a pity,that for each call to firstName with different arguments i have to query to the database ,i know the second time it wont go to the database,but i want that behaviour at the first time,taking advantage that i already thave the full table in memory.

Comment: Why Redis over Ehcache and other Mentioned ones? Ehcache and others belongs to "Cache" category of the tech stack, while Redis can be primarily classified under "In-Memory Databases". What extra support you are getting is you can use it as database if you want, it provides predefined data structure (Set/list) i.e store it in one language and get it in another, master slave configuration and many more. If you don't have complex problem and your cache is just processed in java alone, Redis is something that you dont need. Ehcache is enough for that

Comment: Redis stores data as key value pair.. So technically you cannot search inside your value with a key because separate definition need to be given like which data should be considered as key and what should be the corresponding value which itself makes it as a complex idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!I get the idea,i just need to save in the cache the data from one table (this table wont change ever),and when the user wants some data,use the cache.The problem,it s that cache is using key-value saved data,each time i want some particular data ,i need to go to perform the query (Get the book with THIS id ),and that result related to that id,it s cached,so next time some user wants that book,it s cached.Like i told you before,it s a pity i cant use all the data i already have cached.

Comment: So i guess this is my only option,or to getAllBooks(They are all cached) ,and loop over the list to find the correct one based on the id.I dont know which of the options are more expensive.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**Spring boot** manages the cache per application or per service. When you are using multiple instance of a service or app then certainly you'll want to manage the cache centrally. Because per service cache is not usable in this case because what one app caches in its own **spring boot** is logically not accessible by another apps.

So here **Redis** comes into picture. If you use **Redis**, then each instance of service will connect to the same Redis cache and get the same result.